# List of Enums C#

Tags: c#

Am using an api where I need to set a list of days in a week, there is a enum for these days but I cannot use List. The parameter is expecting something like this RecurringDay.Monday | RecurringDay.Wednesday

I cannot seem to find a means of building this up with the values I have for my days without doing it in a way that seems very poor coding. How can I construct a list of days a user selects like RecurringDay.Monday | RecurringDay.Wednesday | RecurringDay.Friday

```
[Flags]
public enum RecurringDay
{
    RecurringNone = 0,
    RecurringSunday = 1,
    RecurringSaturday = 2,
    RecurringWeekend = 3,
    RecurringFriday = 4,
    RecurringThursday = 8,
    RecurringWednesday = 16,
    RecurringTuesday = 32,
    RecurringMonday = 64,
    RecurringWeekdays = 124,
    RecurringAlldays = 127
}

schedule.LocalTime = new HueDateTime()
{
  DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
  RecurringDay = RecurringDay.RecurringMonday | RecurringDay.RecurringAlldays
};
```

Comment: I would have set `RecurringWeekend = RecurringSunday | RecurringSaturday` and likewise with `RecurringWeekdays` and `RecurringAllDays` but that's about the only change I see from what you have. What exactly is it that you're referring to as "very poor coding"?

Comment: Enums are just structures which are like classes without methods. So access it by structurename.day.. Which can be achieved if you remove Recurring part from each of the enum values.. For the list you can use List<int> list;

Comment: What is the question here?  Your code seems fine to me, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Maybe you could use Dictionary<int,string>? but your code is cleaner though

Comment: For what it's worth, Enum.Parse<EnumType> might help here (your question is a little vague).  After getting rid of all your "Recurring", you can parse a string like "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday" and you will get a properly typed enum that represent a value those flags set.  You need to fiddle to make sure things are just right, but I've found it's a solution to several problems over the years

Answer (score 6):

Flags enums are bit vectors. Each enum value corresponds to a bit in the underlying integer. Combinations of set bits represents combinations of values. For this to work every value need to be a power of 2, i.e. exactly on bit is set. But combinations of bits may also have names, like `RecurringWeekend` in the above example.

Example:

```
0b00010001 = 0x11 = 17
         1 Sunday included
        0  Saturday not included
       0   Friday not included
      0    Thursday not included
     1     Wednesday included
    0      Tuesday not included
   0       Monday not included
```

To build up such a combination just use the |= operator:

```
RecurringDay days = RecurringDay.RecurringNone;
if (user_selected_Sunday)
  days |= RecurringDay.RecurringSunday;
if (user_selected_Saturday)
  days |= RecurringDay.RecurringSaturday;
...
if (user_selected_Monday)
  days |= RecurringDay.RecurringMonday;
```

At the end `day` will contain the appropriate combination of days matching the users selection.

In fact every instance of a flags enum value *is* already a set of values which of course might also be empty, i.e. `RecurringDay.RecurringNone`. No need to use `List<>` here.

Comment: This is nice, and I am not fully understand the working nags of it but isn’t it defeating the readability that enums offer..

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed. Didn't know |= was an operator

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your question is, but this code looks fine to me.  First, I got rid of your recurring "Recurring", and made the combinations more clear (as @Heretic Monkey suggested):

```
[Flags]
public enum RecurringDay
{
    None = 0,
    Sunday = 1,
    Saturday = 2,
    Friday = 4,
    Thursday = 8,
    Wednesday = 16,
    Tuesday = 32,
    Monday = 64,
    Weekends = Saturday | Sunday,
    Weekdays = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday,
    Alldays = Weekdays | Weekends,
}
```

Then I recreated your HueDateTime class with property names that weren't type names (for clarity):

```
public class HueDateTime
{
    public DateTime When { get; set; }
    public RecurringDay HowOften { get; set; }
}
```

Then I consumed the code:

```
var schedule = new HueDateTime()
{
    When = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
    HowOften = RecurringDay.Monday | RecurringDay.Wednesday
};

var succeeded = Enum.TryParse<RecurringDay>("Sunday,Monday,Tuesday", out var when);
```

When that last statement finishes executing, `succeeded`is `true` and `when` is typed as a `RecurringDay` with a value of `Sunday | Tuesday | Monday`.  I'm pretty sure this code could easily pass a picky code reviewer.

I just noticed, your days go backwards (Sunday, Saturday ... Tuesday, Monday) - any particular reason?  That's why `when` ends up as `Sunday | Tuesday | Monday`.